# Google Two-factor Authentication Tutorial for Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, two-factor-authentication

Does anyone know a good Google Two-factor Authentication tutorial for Codeigniter?

Comment: Such questions are [not appropriate for this site](http://bit.ly/dcqznq) and will be [closed](http://bit.ly/18T95z1) or [deleted](http://bit.ly/10c3VuR). Be sure to familiarize yourself with [what type of questions you can or should ask](http://bit.ly/r0ZSEc). If you have any question about this, feel free to ask on [Meta](http://bit.ly/SgO5J) or check the [FAQ] and see [About] page for general information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here tutsplus Integrating Two-Factor Authentication with CodeIgniter

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/integrating-two-factor-authentication-with-codeigniter/

Comment: This isn't a tutorial more than it is a sales pitch. How to integrate this "free" service that if you use more than 10 user will require a little something extra.. What I'd like to know is how to setup two factor on my end without some paid for service, that would interest me way more..